# "Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)" in R

Tags: r

I am getting this error when i run this code below to download data

Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE) : Failed to connect to course1.winona.edu port 80: Timed out

Any help would be appreciated

My code

```
library(RCurl)
urlfile <-'http://course1.winona.edu/bdeppa/Stat%20425/Data/Boston_Housing.csv'
downloaded <- getURL(urlfile, ssl.verifypeer=FALSE)
connection <- textConnection(downloaded)
dataset <- read.csv(connection, header=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need anything beyond `read.csv`. This works for me:

```
urlfile <-'http://course1.winona.edu/bdeppa/Stat%20425/Data/Boston_Housing.csv'
dataset <- read.csv(urlfile)
```

Comment: Thank you David. It worked. My error was due to firewall. I tried your code, plus my code outside firewall restrictions and both worked.

Comment: Great! Please click the check-mark to indicate this question has been answered.